# JQuery Promises on An Asynchronous Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a followup to a question I asked yesterday. I'm having a different problem related to jquery promises.

```
                    function setOverrides2() {
                        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
                        // do something
                        return dfd.promise();
                    }

                    function overrideDialog1() {

                        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

                        ConfirmMessage.onConfirmYes = function() {
                            ConfirmMessage.hideAll();
                            // do stuff
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                        ConfirmMessage.onConfirmNo = function() {
                            ConfirmMessage.hideAll();
                            // do stuff
                            deferred.reject();
                        }

                        ConfirmMessage.showConfirmMessage("Do you wish to override primary eligibility?");

                        return deferred.promise();

                    }

                    function overrideDialog2() {

                        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

                        ConfirmMessage.onConfirmYes = function() {
                            ConfirmMessage.hideAll();
                            // do stuff 
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                        ConfirmMessage.onConfirmNo = function() {
                            ConfirmMessage.hideAll();
                            // do stuff
                            deferred.reject();
                        }

                        ConfirmMessage.showConfirmMessage("Do you wish to override secondary eligibility?");

                        return deferred.promise();
                    }

                    setOverrides2().done(function(data) {

                        // shows both dialogs at once
                        overrideDialog().then(overrideDialog2()).then(function() {
                            alert("test");
                        });

                        // waits for one dialog to complete before showing the other
                        //  overrideDialog1().done(function() {
                        //      overrideDialog2().done(function() {
                        //          alert("test two!");
                        //      });
                        //  });
                    });
```

As shown above, when I use done(), it works perfectly, but when I use then(), it shows both dialogs simultaneously. I want to be able to be able to use reject() to abort the chain the first time the user clicks the No button (defined by the onConfirmNo() callback).

The commented .done() section waits for one dialog to finish before triggering the next, but does not abort processing if the user clicks No on the first dialog.

I think I almost have this right, so if anyone can assist on this last piece of the puzzle, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Jason

Comment: You're not passing a function to `then`. If you did (like you do with `done`), it work just as well

Comment: overrideDialog2() is a function. Are you saying I need to pass an anonymous function?

Comment: Nope. `overrideDialog2` is a function, `overrideDialog2()` is not. `function(){ return overrideDialog2(); }` is a function as well.

Comment: DOH! That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
overrideDialog().then(overrideDialog2())
```

Should be:

```
overrideDialog().then(overrideDialog2)
```

The reason `done` was working was because you wrapped it inside a function (which did not immediately execute)